# Group and transforming array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following hash:

```
hash = {"col1"=>["FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE"],
 "col2"=>["FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE"],
 "Freq"=>[36146, 2614, 2607, 1692]}
```

I would like to create an array of two hashes out of the one above by grouping it by **col1**; the first hash would contain :name => "FALSE" and the second hash would contain :name => "TRUE".

The goal is to get the following array of hashes. value1 and value2 in the first hash below correspond to frequencies attributed to FALSE and TRUE in col2.

```
 [{name=> FALSE, value1 =>  36146, value2 =>  2607 },
 {name=> TRUE, value1 =>  2614, value2 =>  1692 }]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Some corrections are needed `name`, `value1` and `value2` must be convert to strings (`"name"`) or symbols (`:name`). `FALSE` and `TRUE` must be converted to strings, symbols or to the object `false` or `true`. See my answer for ideas.

Comment: You need to edit to clarify the question. If my understanding is correct, something like: "I wish to create an array of two hashes. The first hash contains `:name => "FALSE"` and two other key-value pairs.  The keys (values) are the values of `hash["col2"]` (`hash["Freq"]`) at the offsets of the values of `hash["col1"]` which equal "FALSE" (here offsets `0` and `2`, so that would be `"FALSE"=>36146"` and `"TRUE"=>2607`). The second hash is constructed similarly, except it is for the elements of `hash["col1"]` that equal `"TRUE"` (here at offsets `1` and `3`)." Feel free to use any of this.

Comment: When I say corrections and clarification are needed, I mean you need to edit your question. As there are presently three votes to close, you should do that *post haste*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this produces the array of hashes you want. I have changed the names of some values to make the results more understandable.

```
hash = {"col1"=>["FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE"],
        "col2"=>["FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE"],
        "Freq"=>[36146, 2614, 2607, 1692]}

arr = hash["col1"].zip(hash["col2"], hash["Freq"])
  #=> [["FALSE", "FALSE", 36146], ["TRUE", "FALSE", 2614],
  #    ["FALSE", "TRUE",   2607], ["TRUE", "TRUE",  1692]]

arr.each_with_object({}) do |(tf1,tf2,freq),h|
  (h[tf1] ||= {})[:name] = tf1+?1
   h[tf1][tf2+?2] = freq
end.values
  #=> [{:name=>"FALSE1", "FALSE2"=>36146, "TRUE2"=>2607},
  #    {:name=>"TRUE1", "FALSE2"=>2614, "TRUE2"=>1692}]
```

[Enumerable#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) is used to produce the array `arr` whose value is shown above.

```
enum = arr.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["FALSE", "FALSE", 36146], ["TRUE", "FALSE", 2614],
  #   ["FALSE", "TRUE", 2607], ["TRUE", "TRUE", 1692]]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can convert the enumerator to array to see what values it will pass into its blocK:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[["FALSE", "FALSE", 36146], {}], [["TRUE", "FALSE", 2614], {}],
  #    [["FALSE", "TRUE", 2607],   {}], [["TRUE", "TRUE", 1692],  {}]]
```

Note that the value of the hash in elements after the first (shown in each as `{}`) will be non-empty by the time the element is passed into the block.

The first array,

```
[["FALSE", "FALSE", 36146], {}]
```

is passed into the block, decomposed and assigned to the block variables:

```
tf1 = "FALSE"
tf2 = "FALSE"
freq = 36146
h    = {}
```

We then perform the following operations:

```
(h[tf1] ||= {})[:name] = tf1+?1
  # (h["FALSE"] ||= {})[:name] = "FALSE"+?1
  # h["FALSE"] = h["FALSE"] || {})[:name] = "FALSE1"
  # h["FALSE"] = nil || {})[:name] = "FALSE1"
  # h["FALSE"] = {})[:name] = "FALSE1"
  # h => {"FALSE"=>{:name=>"FALSE1"}}

h[tf1][tf2+?2] = freq
  # h["FALSE"]["FALSE"] = 36146
  # h => {"FALSE"=>{:name=>"FALSE1", "FALSE"=>36146}}
```

After each of the other elements of `enum` are passed into the block, we have:

```
h
  #=> {"FALSE"=>{:name=>"FALSE1", "FALSE2"=>36146, "TRUE2"=>2607},
  #    "TRUE"=> {:name=>"TRUE1",  "FALSE2"=>2614,  "TRUE2"=>1692}}
```

The final step is to extract the values of this hash:

```
h.values
  #=> [{:name=>"FALSE1", "FALSE2"=>36146, "TRUE2"=>2607},
  #    {:name=>"TRUE1",  "FALSE2"=>2614,  "TRUE2"=>1692}]
```

Comment: Great use case of each_with_object. Thanks for the prompt response.